# Cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'G Details'

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Ι am trying to populate data into different tables from a common form which contains sub forms.

When Ι enter data in the first form everything shows fine, but when Ι try to enter data in the other forms, a message pops up saying

> you cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table'G details'.

It's creating problem as Ι have to create a report, also which Ι wont be able to make without solving this problem.

Common data is "PO No" for all the forms.
Please help me solving this problem.

I am attaching my [ACCESS DATABASE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B495vLJfguM-bFJMejEzUnhkc3M/view?usp=sharing) so that you will be able to understand my problem correctly if Ι forgot to mention anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to remove 'access' as it is already there with tags. I also fixed some spelling and properly formatted several parts - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit your question to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that for all subform controls you have specicified the `MasterLinkField` to be *Po No* where it must be *Id* as to your table relations.

Comment: thanks for the reply
i changed the relationship as per masterlink to be "id" for all the subforms, but the problem is same and its not working.
Any further suggestions ?

The overall concept of the Datasheet is:

Data of every subform should be connected to a specific PO No.

Comment: It worked here after the change, so I can't tell. The PO No should for all subforms be fetched from the main table via the Id and not stored in the sub tables.

Comment: can you send me the database??
it will be a great help

Comment: i am unable to understand "The PO No should for all subforms be fetched from the main table via the Id and not stored in the sub tables"

Comment: The database is here: [Final1](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9A761BDD515E1B67!57334&authkey=!AEHOmPZo4cLoLsY&ithint=file%2caccdb). As for the PO No, this is about _normalization_ and _referential integrity_ which you can browse for.